# Why won't my R script plot points when using the "points" function?

Tags: r, plot, point

I'm trying to create a vertical profile based on data I have collected and entered into R. When I use the points(x,y) function, the points aren't showing up on my plot and I'm not sure what to do about it. I have to use the "points" function three separate times, two of the times it works, and the last time it doesn't, so I know I did it right the two other times, I'm just not sure about the last one.

Here is what I tried :

```
plot(TitAvg, ylim=rev(range(Depths)), xlab='Relative O2 Concentrations (mmol/kg)', 
     ylab='Depth (m)', col='black')
points(SEPercent, Depths, pch=23, )
points(ElectPercentKG, Depths, col='blue')
points(ARGOO2, Depths, col='green')
```

The one that isn't working is points(ARGOO2,Depths, col = 'green'). I have uploaded an image of the plot I'm getting minus the ARGOO2 data since it won't plot.

My values for ARGOO2 are:
 `ARGOO2 = c(39.262, 50.385, 96.295, 161.252, 158.647, 176.662, 178.271, 202.726, 212.455, 211.404)`
My values for Depths are:
`Depths = c(605.4878049, 538.4146341, 471.3414634, 404.2682927, 337.195122, 270.1219512, 203.0487805, 135.9756098, 68.90243902, 1.829268293)` 
Let me know if you need any other information to help me solve this, or if there is just a simple error in my code.

Thank you!

Comment: Please add `TitAvg`,  `SEPercent`, and `ElectPercentKG` so we can replicate the plot/issue. Something like `plot(c(min(ARGOO2), max(ARGOO2)), c(min(Depths), max(Depths)), type = "n"); points(x = ARGOO2, y = Depths, col = 'green'); points(y = ARGOO2, x = Depths, col = "blue")` works. But obviously not all blue points can be displayed as they lie outside the plot margins. I assume you have a similar issue.

Comment: In `points` you provide `y=Depths` whereas in `points` you don't provide them, that's inconsistent.